# Can I keep effects like Layer Weight intact after editing normals?

Tags: node-editor, normals, lighting

I have applied a data transfer to smooth the normals on my model to get better lighting, however when I apply layer weight to my shader or a different node that uses normals I can't seem to replicate it the way it was before.

How would I restore the normals just for the node and not for the lighting on the model? Thank you in advance :).

Comment: Is the data transfer dynamic, or have you applied the modifier?  I know you said you "applied" it, but I mean by actually doing an apply modifier operation, and the terms is used by some just to mean adding the modifier to the modifier stack.

Comment: I wouldn't really matter if I added it to the modifier stack or not right? The shader would be applied after anyways? Maybe I should rephrase it a little. Can I add a node before the data transfer calculation somehow?

Comment: Well, there are two ways to do this.  One is to bake a normal map, selected to active, from a model without custom normals to a model with, and then use that to get your normals for your layer weight-- but that won't work with dynamic custom normals that you'd get with a live data transfer, like one that's used after an armature mod.  The other way is to write a copy of your vertex normals to an attribute via geometry nodes before your data transfer, but that might not work if you're doing additional deformation, like an armature mod, *after* your data transfer.  Which works better for you?

Comment: I'll try baking normals in substance, but I'm intrigued about the geometry node method, how would I go about doing it? Would it also still work in 2.93?

Comment: Wouldn't work in 2.93.  Requires 3.0 features.